# How can print in the console the values from a JSOP data set from the World Bank?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

How can print in the console the values from a JSOP object I have in my console. When I try to retrieve the name of the country with var countries = data.name prints undefined in the console. I noticed that the tags in the JSONP object are numbers. I am wondering if I have to write a route using those numbers, but when I try to do it, it doesn't work either.

```
var Getdata = function(data) {
console.log(data)

var countries = data.name;
console.log(countries)

}

var url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/DT.DOD.PVLX.CD?date=2015&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata';

var query_url = url;
console.log(query_url);

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = query_url;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: in the callback function `var Getdata = function(data) {` - data is a javascript Array, not something you call a `JSONP data set` ... just a plain ol' javascript array that you can manipulate like any other javascript array

Comment: Thanks for the correction. My question now is how do I manipulate it. I got the objects in the console, but I tried to build a variable:

Comment: if you look at the data you get, it's an Array, and in the array there is an object at position 0 - and an array of objects at position 1 ... and none of the objects have a property called `name`

Comment: `I tried to build a variable` - well `data` has the data ... if you want it to be a global variable, you can say `window.someGlobal = data` in the callback

Comment: Thanks for the correction. My question now is how do I manipulate it. I got the objects in the console, but I tried to build a variable: `var countries = data.name; console.log(countries) ` but that prints undefined in the console, how do I actually get the name of the country.

Comment: because, as I already said, data is an ARRAY ... it does not have a `name` property ... it has two items ... [0] is an object with page, pages, per_page and total properties, and [1] is an array of objects, that have indicator, country, value, decimal and date properties ... nowhere is there a name property in that data at all, so there's no way of knowing what you expect "countries" to be

Comment: Ok, I see. And how do I access lets say to the property of country and value? if I write `var countries = data.country; console.log(countries)` it prints in the console undefined

Comment: because as I've said TWICE now, data is an ARRAY - see the answer I've posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the data,

```
[
    // this is data[0]
    {
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 6,
        "per_page": "50",
        "total": 264
    }, 
    // this is data[1]
    [
        // this is data[1][0]
        {
            "indicator": {
                "id": "DT.DOD.PVLX.CD",
                "value": "Present value of external debt (current US$)"
            },
            "country": {
                "id": "1A",
                "value": "Arab World"
            },
            "value": null,
            "decimal": "0",
            "date": "2015"
        }, 
        // data[1][1 ... 49] below here
        ... etc
    ]
]
```

to get a list of countries

```
var countries = data[1].map(function(item) {
    return item.country.value;
});
```

> **Of course, you're only getting a list of the first 50 countries in that result, you would need to call that API with some parameter to get the next 5 pages (you have page 1 of 6)**

so

```
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/DT.DOD.PVLX.CD?date=2015&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata&page=2  
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/DT.DOD.PVLX.CD?date=2015&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata&page=3
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/DT.DOD.PVLX.CD?date=2015&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata&page=4
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/DT.DOD.PVLX.CD?date=2015&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata&page=5
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/DT.DOD.PVLX.CD?date=2015&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata&page=6
```

Need to be retrieved as well

Here's a way you can retrieve all countries

```
var Getdata = (function() {
    var url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/DT.DOD.PVLX.CD?date=2015&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata';
    var allCountries = [];
    var callback;

    return function Getdata(data) {
        var hdr,
            arr, 
            countries;
        if (typeof data == 'function') {
            // called by code
            callback = data; // setup the callback
            allCountries = [];
        } else {
            // called by JSONP type callback
            hdr = data[0];
            arr = data[1];

            countries = arr.map(function(item) {
                return item.country.value;
            });
            allCountries = allCountries.concat(countries);
        }
        if (!hdr || hdr.page < hdr.pages) {
            // get the first (hdr is undefined) or next page
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = url + (hdr ? '&page=' + (hdr.page + 1) : '');
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        } else {
            // done, callback the countries
            callback(allCountries);
        }
    };
})();
```

The just call

```
Getdata(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that really worked for me. Really appreciated.

Comment: @CésarBarboza - I've added code that will read the next 5 pages as well, then a supplied callback is called with the results of ALL 6 pages